# I just changed my brakes and hear a knocking noise when i stop accelerating

Tags: brakes, noise

My brakes were squeaking so I just bought new brake pads and replaced them. The squeaking is gone but I noticed driving that when I let off the accelerator it makes a knocking noise and the steering wheel starts to shake a little. Any suggestions and thank you

Answer (score 3):

Did you tighten your wheel nuts correctly?

This could be a very possible cause.

Check them ASAP.

Comment: Yes, learn from my experience. Torque your lug nuts.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention changing the rotors so I'll assume you reused them.  The rotors are bedded-in to the old pads and very often new pads don't sit right against the new one right away.  You may see this improve with time.

The best procedure is to replace or resurface the rotors along with the pads.

Comment: Does this explain the knocking noise and steering wheel shake?

Comment: I think it does.